# How can I split spring array into a char array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I turn ['Tom', 'Mary', 'Jerry']

into

['T', 'o' ,'m' ,'M' ,'a' ,'r' ,'y' ,'J' ,'e' ,'r' ,'r' ,'y']

without turning the starting array into a string?

Comment: Why without turning the starting array into a string?

Comment: Please add the code you've tried.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Array#flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [String#split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
const input = ['Tom', 'Mary', 'Jerry'];
const result = input.flatMap(v => v.split(''));
console.log(result);
```